# Htmlize magit-log

Tags: magit

I would like to htmlize my magit-log. When I try i get:

> htmlize-get-text-with-display: Args out of range: " * ", 0, -3

Is there a workaround around?

Answer (score 1):

Same here. `Magit` uses some overlay margin to display author/date and that is not handled properly by `htmlize`.

if you don't need the author/date margin, here's 2 way to disable it :

- inside the log window press `L` then `t`
- `(setq magit-log-show-margin nil)`

Edit: turns out that's not sufficent. if evaluate `(defun magit-format-log-margin (&optional authordate))` (redefine as an empty function) it should work.

Comment: It would be nicer to fix this in `htmlize`.

Comment: It worked!. I can copy the log-buffer to a new file buffer and htmlize that. The magin-stuff is gone, but the coloring and fonts is working.